# User-defined formula not updating after opening Excel 2013 and acknowledging Security Warning

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2013

After opening an Excel 2013 Worksheet, I get the following messages:

- "Protected View - Be careful ..." and the button "Enable Editing"
- "Security Warning - Some active content has been disabled. Click for more details." and the button "Enable Content".

These are expected messages that pop up in accordance to my Trust Center Settings, as I use macros and user-defined functions stored in my add-in.

The problem I'm recently experiencing is, that I'm get different results depending on how I acknowledge the "Security Warning":

a) If I click the "Enable Content" button, then my custom formulas return the #NAME? error in those cells that contain my user-defined formulas (e.g. ufCombineRanges).  Re-calculating manually (F9) doesn't solve the problem.  On the other hand, if I select the cell, edit it (F2) and press Enter, then the formula computes and continues to update correctly after that.

[Result after pressing Security Warning "Enable Content" Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b48UM.jpg)

b) If I click the "X" button, then my custom formulas compute and continue to update correctly.

[Result after pressing Security Warning X Button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWCSZ.jpg)

When using the user-defined formula in a brand new worksheet, this does not happen.  The problem seems to be related to the way Excel updates the formulas after pressing that "Enable Content" button.

Any ideas what the cause could be, i.e. how this can be fixed?

Is there a function that can be called, that will update the user-defined formulas, other than the equivalent of F9?

Any help/ideas are greatly appreciated.

FYI:  This is the code for the user-defined function:

```
Function ufCombineRanges(Separator As String, ParamArray Ranges() As Variant) As String
    Application.Volatile
    Dim i As Long
    Dim TheRange As Variant
    For i = LBound(Ranges) To UBound(Ranges)
        For Each TheRange In Ranges(i)
            If TheRange.Text <> "" Then
                OutStr = OutStr & TheRange.Text & Separator
            End If
         Next TheRange
    Next i
    If Len(OutStr) > 0 Then
        ufCombineRanges = Left(OutStr, Len(OutStr) - Len(Separator))
    Else
        ufCombineRanges = ""
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: After some additional testing, I've been able to reproduce the issue.  The update problem goes away as I set my Trust Center Settings (go to:  Options --> Trust Center --> Trust Center Settings --> Macro Settings) from "Disable all macros with notification" to "Enable all macros".  Not a great solution, but is a workaround.  Looks like this is an Excel bug.  Still would like to find out if there is a way to fix this by using some VBA code (maybe there is a way to delay the formula update after the "Enable Content" button gets pressed?).  Any ideas?

Comment: It would be useful to see your code.  My guess is `Application.Volatile` hasn't been set correctly but without code it is hard to tell.

Comment: I included the code of the UDF.  The Application.Volatile was already added.  Thanks.

Comment: FWIW - that function doesn't need to be marked as `Volatile` - all information being used by it is passed as parameters, and therefore Excel can safely keep track of when a calculation needs to performed.

Comment: Thanks for the note.  It seems that having `Volatile` or not doesn't have any effect on the result.

Answer (score 0):

If the UDFs are in linked workbooks/add-ins, then you should be able to Edit Links.. Change-Source or Check-Status.

If the UDFs are defined in the *same* workbook, you might need to update all of the formulas. The easy way to do that is to Find/Replace all "=" with "=", which effectively changes all of your formulas without actually changing them, but it's enough to make Excel calculate the cells. Then save, and you shouldn't have the problem again.

Comment: Thanks for commenting.  The Excel file of the above example calls UDFs contained in a .xlam file, which is automatically loaded from the c:\Program Files\Microsoft Office 15\root\office15\XLSTART\ directory when the Excel file is opened.  The .xlam file is referenced by the VBA Project so that the modules can "see" the UDF (e.g. the ufCombineRanges function).  In other words, the UDF is defined in the referenced Add-in, not in the same workbook.  Nevertheless, the described Find/Replace does the trick!

Comment: --- Just to understand:  what do you mean exactly with Edit Links/Change Course/Check-Status?